# How to make PowerShell functions permanent for non-elevated shells?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to have a PowerShell function loaded every time I open any PowerShell terminal (non-elevated included!). I tried the following:

1. `mkdir "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Functions"`
2. Add my functions as *.ps1-files to the directory
3. Open $profile (`if (!(Test-Path (Split-Path $profile))) { mkdir (Split-Path $profile) } ; if (!(Test-Path $profile)) { New-Item $profile -ItemType file } ; notepad $profile`)
4. Add this to the profile:

```
# Load own custom functions at startup
$OwnFunctionsDir = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Functions"
Write-Host "Loading own PowerShell functions from:" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "$OwnFunctionsDir" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Get-ChildItem "$OwnFunctionsDir\*.ps1" | %{.$_}
Write-Host ''
```

And it works with elevated shells but with non-elevated ones it just doesn't load anything. How can I make it work with non-elevated shells?

| elevated | non-elevated |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: What happens in a non-elevated shell? Error messages? Nothing?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Nothing happens and nothing is printed. In elevated shells, I get the `Loading own PowerShell functions from: xxx` print.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I added some pictures for reference

Comment: your picture [ick!] shows that your profile is NOT loading in one of them. that means you saved the profile to a file that is NOT available to the failing account.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey How do I fix this tho? I used an elevated shell to create the profile.

Comment: you need to find out which profile location is used for each instance. you can find that with `$profile`. if they are NOT different, then the problem is something else.

Comment: @leonheess No problem bud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my "My Documents" path was not set correctly. This is how I fixed it:

1. Open regedit.exe
2. Browse to the following path: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`
3. Find the registry key `Personal`
4. Change its value to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`
5. Restart the computer
6. Repeat steps 3. and 4. from the question